# Error occuring when running c++ code in gdb: [Inferior 1 (process 9985) exited normally]

Tags: c++, gdb

When I run my `c++` code using gdb, above error appears. I type `where` to locate the problem but the output is `No stack`.
What is the problem and how should I solve it?

Comment: Can you please improve the title, and adjust the tags to include GDB?

Comment: Sure, I did. Do you know where the problem originates from? @usr1234567

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should set break point or watch point to stop program,then show stacks or other information.
If you do not stop it and run to the end ,then it shows [exited normally]. There is nothing special , it's just because the program finished and exit(such as return or exit in main normally).

Comment: Oh, I didn't really know that. So it means there is no bug in my code and it has been run without any problem, am I correct?

Comment: there is no  compiling time error ,no big run time error that make your process crash.But I can't say your code is ok without view your code . If the program function do not work as you wish , it is a bug, there are many bugs won't let your program crash , such as memory leak. you need test your program,such as print out put to screen.